# Some confusions about implementing realm in swift

Tags: swift, realm

I want to learn realm. I searched about it on the internet but I have some doubts about it. I am using swift language for it. So which file should I import in my class

```
import Realm
```

OR

```
import RealmSwift
```

while create class for real table from which class it will be inherited means from `RLMObject` or `Object` and for making object array which Thing I will use `List` or `RLMArray`

I have downloaded realm's latest version on proper site but still its print log tells that latest version available.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Awesome! Glad to hear you're interested in learning Realm!

At this point, there are 2 discrete versions of Realm for iOS, the Objective-C version, and the Swift version. `RLMObject`/`RLMArray` is the Objective-C version and `Object/List` is the native Swift version.

Before the native version of Realm for Swift was released, a 'bridged' version was released that simply let you use the Objective-C version in a Swift codebase.

At this point, I would recommend moving completely over to the Swift version of Realm (Which is the `import RealmSwift` keyword you mentioned above).

We released v0.95.1 of Realm yesterday; very recently. So if you're seeing an upgrade notice, you can fix that by completely deleting that version of Realm you downloaded (Which cleans out the prebuilt copies of the framework), and re-downloading it again.

**(Disclaimer: I work for Realm)**

Comment: thanks you Tim. it's help me a lot. just one point can you please give me a proper document/website link for implementing realm in swift. I have read https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/ but it here not brief information about it.

Comment: as per you suggestion I have download latest swift realm framework as well as update my code. but I have stuck on "How to write Sub query?"

Comment: No worries! The Swift documentation should be self-explanatory on how the framework works. Aside from that, we have the actual API documentation: https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/.  If you're having trouble, make sure to also check out the Swift examples in that Realm download. They can really help ground how the framework works in code. :)